# Intersection of normal subgroups and their indices exercise

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $H\leq G$, and $H$ is a simple group such that $[G:H]=2.$
>
> Prove:
>
> $H$ is the only normal subgroup of $G$ or there is a normal subgroup $K\leq G$, $|K|=2$ such that $G=H \times K.$

**My idea:**

$[G:H]=2 \implies |H|=\frac{|G|}{2}$

Suppose there is a normal subgroup $K\leq G$.

We know that $H \cap K=\{1\}$ or $H \cap K=H$ since $H$ is a simple subgroup.

If $K=\{e\} \implies H$ is the only normal subgroup (except $\left\{ 1\right\}$ and $G$ itself).

If $K=H \implies H$ is the only normal subgroup (except $\left\{ 1\right\}$ and $G$ itself).

If $K \neq \{1\}$ and $H \cap K=\{1\}$ then $|HK|=|G|$ ,HK is a subgroup since $H,K$ are normal subgroup. Also $|H|=\frac{|G|}{2},|K|=|2|,H \cap K= \{ 1\}, G=HK \implies G =HK \simeq H \times K.$

If $H \cap K=H$
$  |H|=\frac{|G|}{2}\leq |K| \leq |G| \implies |K|=|G| \implies H$ is the normal subgroup (except $\left\{ 1\right\}$ and $G$ itself).

I'd be grateful for your some help!

Comment: The problem statement is wrong. You should have that either $H$ is the only normal subgroup of $G$, or there is a normal subgroup $K$ with $|K|=2$ (the *size* of $K$, not the index) with $G=H\times K$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes , excuse my bad English!

Comment: To see the statement is incorrect, just look at $G=A_5\times C_2$ and $H=A_5\times\{1\}$. Then $H$ is simple, it is *not* the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$, but the only other nontrivial proper normal subgroup is $\{e\}\times C_2$, which does not have index $2$: it has index $60$. But it has **order** $2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed my solution , hope its correct now

Comment: 1. "...such that $|K|\gt m\neq 2$." That's not what you want to assume. What is $m$, anyway?  2. You don't know that $H\cap K=\{1\}$. You know that either $H\cap K=\{1\}$, or $H\cap K=H$. 3. You know that $HK=G$ *except* in the case $H=K$ (which you have not excluded at any point) or $K=\{e\}$.  4. You *already* know $|H|=|G|/2$, so it is not a "then", it is a given. 5. You claim $|K|=|K|/2$ which is patently wrong.

Comment: thank you ! fixed it

Comment: 1. "If $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $HK=G$". No, you don't know that; what if $K=\{e\}$? "If $H\cap K=H$... "$|K|=|G|$". 2. No, you don't know that. What if $K=H$?  3. Your conclusion that $H$ is the (unique) normal subgroup does not follow in that case, because it could be that the $K$ you picked first was $G$, but that there are other normal subgroups besides the one you picked. You are close, but this is still garbled.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I dont know what if K=H ? is it same subgroup , i fixed it but i am not sure

Comment: You start by saying "Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$". You place absolutely no conditions on $K$. So if I were following your proof and "testing" it, I could think "Okay, I'm going to let $K=H$ and see if the argument works."  Your previous argument didn't, because it essentially asserted that you would never have $K=H$. As to your current effort, you are still writing your conclusions wrong. You just took a *single* normal subgroup; you cannot deduce from what happens to one normal subgroup what happens to **every** normal subgroup. (cont)

Comment: Right now you are literally saying that if you happen to look at the trivial subgroup of $G$ that **immediately implies** that $H$ is the only nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $G$. That is just plain false. What you wrote now is even more muddled than what you had before. Don't jump to conclusions! See what possibilities you have *first*, then see what some of them happening or not happening mean for $G$.